# How to use groupby and value_counts on a column with multiple categories?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I have column `marital-status` in a dataframe that has the following **unique** values:
'Married-civ-spouse', 'Married-spouse-absent', 'Married-AF-spouse', 'Divorced', 'Widowed', and 'Separated'.
I want to use `groupby` and `value_counts` functions to get the percentage of each income category to be like

```
marital-status  salary
Bachelor        <=50K     0.935546
                >50K      0.064454
Married         <=50K     0.563080
                >50K      0.436920
```

Instead of:

```
marital-status         salary
Divorced               <=50K     0.895791
                       >50K      0.104209
Married-AF-spouse      <=50K     0.565217
                       >50K      0.434783
Married-civ-spouse     <=50K     0.553152
                       >50K      0.446848
Married-spouse-absent  <=50K     0.918660
                       >50K      0.081340
Never-married          <=50K     0.954039
                       >50K      0.045961
Separated              <=50K     0.935610
                       >50K      0.064390
Widowed                <=50K     0.914401
                       >50K      0.085591
```

Knowing that anything which begins with 'Married' is considered 'Married'.Otherwise, it is considered as 'Bachelor'.

Actually, I tried to use `replace` function to replace any value that begins with 'Married' as 'Married' and 'Bachelor' otherwise. But I want another method that can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another column with Married-Bachelor as the only two values using the `np.where` function and then use groupby.

```
df['marital_status_new'] = np.where(df['marital-status'].str.contains('Marriage'), 'Marriage', 'Bachelor')

df.groupby('marital_status_new')['salary'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: It worked! but with changing the position of `salary` to be outside the groupby function like that df.groupby('marital-status')['salary'].....